# Unable to display directory content in array

Tags: arrays, bash

I am trying to a) count how many files I have on my mass filer EMC device, b) load them in an array c) display a count of how many files I have d) bulk load each file in my database e) display the name of the file I just loaded.

This is my code...

```
export OUT=/path/to/device
P_Array=$(cd ${OUT} ; find . -name "*TXT" | wc -l)
Plen=${#P_Array[@]}
echo "$Plen FILES TO PROCESS."                                       
if [ $Plen -eq 0 ]
then
        echo "`date '+%m/%d/%y %T:'` ZERO FILES."                  
fi

for name in ${P_Array[@]}
do
        ###Database Bulk Load Here###
        echo "`date '+%m/%d/%y %T:'` $name was loaded."
done
```

Problem A: `Plen=${#P_Array[@]}` displays a count of 1 when it should be 5 (sandbox env, right now).
Problem B: `$name` display the total number of files instead of the individual file name.

Obviously, this is all wrong. I am sure I have something switched around but I am not sure what it is. Help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you do `wc -l` on the result of `find` it's going to give the number of files. Hence, the P_Array contains only one number. So `Plen` is just 1.

Change them to:

```
P_Array=$(cd ${OUT} ; find . -name "*TXT")
Plen=$(cd ${OUT} ; find . -name "*TXT" | wc -l)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make `P_Array` an actual array, not just a list of space-separated words in a string:

```
P_Array=( $(cd ${OUT} ; find . -name "*TXT") )
Plen=${#P_Array[@]}
```

If any of the files have spaces in the file name, this won't work, as such a file will wind up as a sequence of partial file names in the array. In that case, you'll have to do something like

```
pushd "$OUT"         # Switch to the desired directory
P_array=( *TXT )
popd                 # Return to the previous directory, if you like.
Plen=${#P_Array[@]}
```

(Actually, that's probably a better idea than using `find` in the first place.  )

---

If you use an array, you've abandoned POSIX compliance, so here is the rest of your script, simplified with more bash-isms:

```
date_fmt='%m/%d/%y %T'
if (( Plen = 0 ))
then
    # $(...) is still POSIX, but is also preferred over backticks
    # printf is also preferred, and you can transfer the formatting
    # from date to the printf.
    printf "%($date_fmt)T: ZERO FILES\n" $(date +%s)
fi

# Quote the array expansion, in case of space-containing filenames
for name in "${P_Array[@]}"
do
    ###Database Bulk Load Here###
    # (be sure to quote $name when doing the bulk load)
    printf "%($date_fmt)T: $name was loaded\n" $(date +%s)
done
```

Comment: right on. This is another problem I have been dealing with. At times, our suppliers feel frisky and send us files with spaces.